# Python, GDAL and building raster attribute tables

Tags: python, raster, gdal, attribute-table

I have an integer raster for which I would like to build a raster attribute table using Python and GDAL. I can create a GDAL raster attribute table in Python as follows:

```
>>> rat = gdal.RasterAttributeTable()
```

This works fine, as we can see:

```
>>> rat
<osgeo.gdal.RasterAttributeTable; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALRasterAttributeTableShadow *' at 0x0000000002A53D50> >
```

The table thus created has no rows or columns:

```
>>> rat.GetRowCount()
0
>>> rat.GetColumnCount()
0
```

I create a column called "Value" to store the unique values in the raster:

```
>>> rat.CreateColumn("Value", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, gdalconst.GFU_MinMax)
0
```

This is fine, and the column count is updated:

```
>>> rat.GetColumnCount()
1
```

Now I have to add values (records) to the column for it to be of any use. I can get a list of unique values from the raster's band like so:

```
>>> data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterYSize)
>>> vals = list(numpy.unique(data))
>>> vals
[3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 41, 45, 52, 56]
```

What I would like to do is create a for loop to loop through `vals` and populate the column in the attribute table. I thought I could do something like this:

```
>>> for i in range(len(vals)):
        rat.SetValueAsInt(i, 0, vals[i])
```

...where `i` is the row (record), `0` is the field index and `vals[i]` is the integer value I want to insert. But it causes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 2, in <module>
    rat.SetValueAsInt(i, 0, vals[i])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 1139, in SetValueAsInt
    return _gdal.RasterAttributeTable_SetValueAsInt(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'RasterAttributeTable_SetValueAsInt', argument 4 of type 'int'
```

The error is caused because I use `vals[i]` in the call to `SetValueAsInt()` rather than using an integer directly. For example, `rat.SetValueAsInt(0, 0, 0)` works fine, but is useless for populating the column if I just want to loop over the list of unique values.

Is this a known issue? Google has so far not been very useful. What can I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SetValueAsInt method is expecting a [python int](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) type, not a [numpy uint16](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) type.

```
>>> print type(vals[0])
<type 'numpy.uint16'>
```

The following works:

```
rat.SetValueAsInt(i, 0, int(vals[i]))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `vals = numpy.unique(data).tolist()` instead it will automatically convert each value to a python int type.